# クリーンアーキテクチャーが実践出来ているか確認する方法は？

Tags: javascript

クリーンアーキテクチャーの実践をしようとしています。
色々な解説書や記事を見たのですが、実践のコードを書くと
このクラスは結局どこに分類されるのか？これらの処理は分けるべきなのか？
が、分からなくなってしまいます。

理想を言えば自分が作ったプログラム一式を提示してこれクリーンアーキテクチャーを適用する方法を教えてくださいと丸投げしたいのですがそれは叶わないので、

**プログラムがどの様な状態であれば、クリーンアーキテクチャーが実践出来ていると判断出来ますか？**

クリーンアーキテクチャーとはそもそもなんぞや？という記事を見ると
「そもそもクリーンアーキテクチャーの本質は名前を付ける事であってよくある図の4階層も必須じゃないんだよ」
みたいな事が書いてあるのを見かけたのですが、それを鵜呑みにして
『クラス名をきっちり付けました！階層は1つも無いけどクリーンアーキテクチャーです！』とはとても言えない事は理解しています。

データ型で何にも依存していないクラスはモデル層。まではなんとなくわかるのですが、
それ以降の処理をどの層に分離したらクリーンアーキテクチャーが実践できていると自称出来るのかが全く分からない状態です。

アプリケーションに必須か？と言われても、現状は必須だけど必須じゃないと表現したいなら必須じゃないとも言えるし…。

言語はnodejsで、作っているのはcliで外部データを読み書きして加工するプログラムです。